# Cardinality of the rings of continuous functions and the algebraic tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, banach-spaces, tensor-products

What are the number of elements in the rings of continuous functions $C(X)$, $C(X\times Y)$ and in the algebraic tensor product $C(X)⊗ C(Y)$? where $X$ and $Y$ are uncountable compact metrizable spaces.
Any useful links ...??

Comment: That depends rather a lot on what $X$ and $Y$ are.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: @RobertShore can you tell me when the cardinalities $C(X \times Y)$ and $C(X)⊗C(Y)$ are equal?

Comment: I had in mind the possibility that $X$ and $Y$ were finite.  Is it true that a compact metrizable space must be separable?  If so, that simplifies the problem a lot.